# How to check if value exists inside javascript Flow type

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, types, flowtype

I have a [Flow](https://flow.org/) type defined as

```
export type fruit = 'apple' | 'orange' | 'pear';
```

What I want to do is validate a string and see if it matches any of the values defined in this type.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use an `array` then validate by using `Array#includes` like this.

```js
const fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear'];
const isValid = anyFruit => fruits.includes(anyFruit);

console.log(isValid("apple"));
console.log(isValid("orange"));
console.log(isValid("pear"));
console.log(isValid("banana"));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help ^^! @Dan Pettis

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about type refinement from a string into one of these values, there's not currently an elegant way of doing this.

A very similar issue was posted here a few days ago [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKakgJwK4CWyoAvKAOQCG660mFoAPpbLlQHYDmDzlWVXBQDciRAGNYHAM4k8RZNLKgA2tVr0KAGlbtuDHRQFCAuqIlTZOfB3HKAFJABcoWbkLcAlC-nE+AN1hCABMyAD5QAG9EUFBCSFBHAmJpADoPcWh8YMxpR09PKJjY0FxMZHxcDhxRWIBfRAaLGTkbcQAmB2dXZHcvH2SSFkCQ8KLY+MSE0hnKGjpeJhZp2Yo2Th5GJZwyVeMKQuiS0vLK6sha0AamyRbrWwBmLpc3Dy5vHEGAoNDSCKPXPBiOIABZTQ7FWLiKjSbDqBYUJyQ0DQ2G6DYMJHHVFw-ZY44nCpVGrFa6IIA) and an issue raised [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKakgJwK4CWyoAvKAOQCG660mFoAPpbLlQHYDmDzlWVXBQDciRAGNYHAM4k8RZNLKgA2tVr0KAGlbtuDHRQFCAuqIlTZOfB3HKAFJABcoWbkLcAlC-nE+AN1hCABMyAD5QAG9EUFBCSFBHAmJpADoPcWh8YMxpR09PKJjY0FxMZHxcDhxRWIBfRAaLGTkbcQAmB2dXZHcvH2SSFkCQ8KLY+MSE0hnKGjpeJhZp2Yo2Th5GJZwyVeMKQuiS0vLK6sha0AamyRbrWwBmLpc3Dy5vHEGAoNDSCKPXPBiOIABZTQ7FWLiKjSbDqBYUJyQ0DQ2G6DYMJHHVFw-ZY44nCpVGrFa6IIA).

To do this with flow and not get errors you need to manually type out the combinations using either an if statement or switch statement,

[try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKakgJwK4CWyoAvKAOQCG660mFoAPpbLlQHYDmDzlWVXBQDciRAGNYHAM4lI+DuLKgAFJABcoWbkLcAlJrxESLAG6xCAEzIA+UAG9EoUJJlyCxacoDa1WvQoAGlZ2bgZgigEhAF1RZ0JIVSNPADpdcWh8S0xpNT09BydnUFxMZHxcDhxhUBBQABUAC0IvKWxMXFw2VvwSACNMcSp8aWxUWHwXTg5YEjQsEsxIXWwR3S4igF9EbYkpWRwFcQAmZTVNbXWDHA8TUHMrW0L4xLUyUnI-Ol4mFkSPz5sTg8Ri-HDvT5RCgFRzFRblSrVLY7MSuA7yRQAZjOGi0yB0+kMtz4D2spDssK08GI4kaSRhRWcQ1GlBo3wo6kZUxZFCBYQ5XOZ2EimEEArhzlKCKqkDioG22yAA)

```
// @flow
type fruit = 'apple' | 'orange' | 'pear';

const func = (f: string): fruit | void => {
  const fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear'];
  if (fruits.includes(f)) {
    return f; // This one errors out because you cannot type refine using
  }
}

const func2 = (f: string): fruit | void => {
  if (f === 'apple' || f === 'orange' || f === 'pear') {
    return f;
  }
}

const func3 = (f: string): fruit | void => {
  switch (f) {
    case 'apple':
    case 'orange':
    case 'pear':
      return f;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely kind of clunky, build you could also do:

```
type FruitMap = {
  apple: '',
  pear: '',
}

const FRUIT_MAP: FruitMap = Object.freeze({
  apple: '',
  pear: '',
});

type Fruit = $Keys<FruitMap>;

const apple = 'apple';
const isFruit = Object.keys(FRUIT_MAP).includes(apple);
```